# Button to redirect

Tags: php, html, button, input

Basically I have a textbox and i want when people paste/write a website inside, and press the button, to be redirected to the site with an extra parameter ("/play/bonus")

```
<input name="website" id="website" type="text" />
<form method="POST" action=document.getElementById('website') & "/play/bonus">
    <input name="pn" value="bonus" type="hidden">
    <button id="bonus" class="btn btn-default navbar-element pull-center">
        <b>50</b> 
        Satoshis
    </button>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('website')
```

Will give the object of that element. You need to use `.value`.

```
document.getElementById('website').value
```

To get the value of element.

And there is no need to use the javascript, I think so. If you are using PHP 
then use `header` function of PHP to redirect.

Your HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="demo.php">
<input name="website" id="website" type="text" />
<input name="pn" value="bonus" type="hidden">
<input id="bonus" type="submit" class="btn btn-default navbar-element pull-center" Value="50 Satoshis">
</form>
```

And your **demo.php** file will be like this:

```
<?php
  $redirect = $_POST['website'];
  header("location:".$redirect."/play/bonus");
```

Comment: There is no need to use php for this issue - that will increase the load on your server, whereas Javascript will put that processing with the client instead. There is also no need to use POST and this would be improved significantly with a GET.

Comment: @AlastairCampbell there is tag of PHP in the question of OP. and there is way to do this with php.

Comment: Because deceze is using PHP. Just because he uses a PHP tag it does not mean that he should use PHP (in this particular instance) for **absolutely no reason**! This is solvable in pure HTML, without the use of PHP or JavaScript. I just feel that JavaScript is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Javascript to do this manually in code rather than making the form POST.

Here's an example for you:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript Form Redirection Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function goToWebsite()
        {
            var url = document.getElementById("inputWebsite").value;
            if (url != null)
            {
                url += "/play/bonus";
                window.location.replace(url);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="inputWebsite" placeholder="Website address"/>
<input type="button" value="Go!" onClick="goToWebsite()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Very simply, what this does is make it so when the button is clicked, it runs the goToWebsite function.

The goToWebsite function:

1. Gets the value of the URL in the text box
2. Checks to make sure that the URL is not null
3. Adds /play/bonus to the end of it
4. Makes the web browser redirect to that page.

Comment: `The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. bonus.html
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`

Comment: Sorry, missed some quotes! that's it sorted now!